# Create a new GIT branch based on server without local changes

Tags: git, git-branch

I think I'm missing some basic idea about GIT branches.

Let's say I've cloned a repository on my machine, and started working (on local "master").

Now someone have told me about a bug in production.

I want to stop everything I'm doing (modified filed and un-pushed commits), create a feature branch that is **based on the server without the changes I made locally**, fix the bug, commit and push, and then get back to master, rebase and keep working.

I thought that the the following would work:

```
$ git clone <some repo>
$ vim text.txt
$ git checkout -b bugFix
```

The problem is that the branch "bugFix" includes the change I made in master in it's status.

How can I create a clean branch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cleanest way is to commit your current work to a local feature-branch (keeping master in releasable state), then switch to master and make the bugfix there (or on a branch based on master).

```
git checkout -b my-feature
git commit -m "add my feature"
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git checkout -b bugFix
... do some work ...
git checkout my-feature
```

If you aren't ready to commit (locally) your work, you can use stash to stash your changes:

```
git stash
git fetch
git checkout origin/master
git checkout -b bugFix
... do some work ...
git checkout master
git stash pop
```

Comment: the first option what I'm going to do, so even of I'm not ready to commit, I'll squash commits. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the remote is named 'origin', the remote branch is called 'production' and you are currently on master - you would do the following:

```
$ git stash   # move your current uncommitted stuff out of the way
$ git checkout -b bugFix remotes/origin/production
# now fix the bug, and commit (to your bugFix branch)
$ git push origin production # back to production
$ git checkout master
$ git stash pop
```

At this point you can delete your local bugFix branch, if you care to, with:

```
$ git branch -d bugFix
```

and you are thus back to where you started (and the company hero besides!)

Answer (score 0):

First, stash what you are doing.

```
git stash
```

Your repository has a remote-tracking branch matching what you last got from origin; switch to that branch.

```
git checkout remotes/origin/master
```

You will be in a detached-head state, since you don't want to commit directly to a remote-tracking branch.  So create a bug fix branch based on the remote-tracking branch.

```
git checkout -b bugFix
```

Hack away